# Translating minicart and other javascript related strings in magento 2.1.3

Tags: javascript, csv, magento, knockout.js

I am learning magento 2, i have started with basics like creating module, then a theme.

Since magento does not come with slovak language i want to do some translation on frontend and later on backend.

I have succeed translating frontend where no javascript / knockout template is used, by placing sk_SK.csv into company/themename/i18n.

I have read about issue on github that in magento 2.0 translation of javascript strings does not work using this method, so i have upgraded to latest version (2.1.3), and its still not working.

I have checked vendor/magento-checkout/i18n/  where the ex. string "Go to Checkout" is defined. So I have tried the override method used also for overriding templates (created company/themename/Magento_Checkout/i18n/sk_SK.csv) and placed the translation here. it does not worked also.

Note: After each change i delete the static folder and run the command to generate static content for sk_SK then i clean the cache and flush the cache, in browser i do hard reload with cleaning cache.

Yes there are lot of topics on github, stackoverflow, docs... but i do not understand them, these answers are written i thing for super professionals.

Note 2: Theoretically i can hard-code slovak language into web/minicart/content.html (not sure if path is right) by overriding this file. But this is not solution for possible multi-language website.

Note 3:
I have did also an export using i18n, but the output is messed up. like "Hello "World"!","something"  same quotes in quotes without escape.its pain to open in any excel kind of app (partly succeed with libreoffice calc) because it has long string and too much strings not friendly for developers or people who will do the translation.

What kind of answer i want to receive is like this:
1. Copy this file here, because..[explanation]
2. Edit/Add/Whatever here, because....
3. etc...

Why? I want to learn and not just copy paste.

Thank you